# How can I print some values ​of data? [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I am using `URLSession` right now. I want to print only the `profile` value among the `userId` and `profile` in the data value here. How can I print it?

**Some of my code**

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
      print( httpResponse.allHeaderFields )
                                          
      guard let data = data else {return}
      print( String (data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" )
                
      let profile = "{\"profile\":\"\(data.profile ?? "")}" // ERROR [Value of type 'Data' has no member 'profile']
                
      }
```

print (String (data: data, encoding: .utf8) ??"") <When I run this code, I get the result like this. `userId` and `profile` I want to display `only the profile` excluding the userId. Thanks for reading.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a type conforming to the Codable protocol and use a JSONDecoder to decode your data to something user friendly.

```
struct UserData: Codable {
    let userId: String
    let profile: String
}
```

Here's how to decode your data:

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

    guard let data = data else { return }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let userData = try decoder.decode(UserData.self, from: data)
        print(userData.profile)
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: The structure you gave me was defined in the AppDelegate, so I thought I could use it. But no, it was solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert data to json and use however you want

```
json = try JSON(data: data)
```

if you want to parse it easily use SwiftyJson

Comment: Using that method, an error of Invalid conversion from throwing function of type'(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type'(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void' Pops up.

Comment: The error code is let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {(data, response, error) in.